# Enumitem Vertical Spaces: Control top and bottom vertical spaces separately

Tags: spacing, lists

I am trying to customize the vertical spacing in `description` environment. A global setting such as:

```
\setlist[description]{%
  topsep=10pt
}
```

adjusts the vertical spacing both “before” and “after” the environment.

What is the proper way to adjust those vertical spaces separately?

Comment: The underlying latex list mechanism does not have separate parameters for space before and after the list, so simplest thing is just to use a correction \vspace after the environment, or need to patch the list implementation to add an extra parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use option `before` and/or option `after` to change the vertical spaces seperatly.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{
  topsep=0pt,
  before=\vspace{20pt},
  %after=\vspace{5pt}
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{description}
\item[Item 1] Text
\item[Item 2] Text
\end{description}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]